# Deleting listview row with SQLite data by click

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to delete a listview row with SQLite data by click.

When I press on the listview item nothing happens, there are no errors in logs.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_meal);

    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView8);

    mHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.MEAL_ID + "=" + mealId.get(arg2), null);
            displayData();
        }
    });

    private void displayData() {
        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
        mealId.clear();
        mealName.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                mealId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_ID)));
                mealName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_NAME)));
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayAdapter disadpt = new DisplayAdapter(NewMealActivity.this, mealId, mealName);
        userList.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info. does your click listener get called? Why are you changing your adapter everytime instead of just updating the cursor. Just clear the list, add the new items and call notifyDataSetChanged on the active Adapter. No reason to recreate each time. Also does your delete code work? it should return "long for num rows deleted" do you get back "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that **`arg2`** is the position within the list which does not equate to the id of the row displayed.

That is if you select the first item, then it's position and thus **arg2** will be **0**.

Assuming that you use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` for the **id** column, then the first ID will probably be 1, the next 2 etc (however you should NEVER rely upon this e.g. if a row is deleted, then that id will very likely not be re-used and the sequence is broken).

**`arg3`** would have the id **BUT ONLY** if the listview utilises a CursorAdapter (I'd suggest this, as then you don't need the intermediate arrays, refreshing the list is simply a matter of rebuilding the cursor and using `swapCursor` or `notifyOnDatasetChanged`, I prefer the former simply because it's more descriptive).

*PS If you do use CursorAdapter then the id column must either be called **_id** (there are ways to rename/create a column via AS in the SELECT query but imo best to use **_id** as the column name in the table).*

As I answered a very similar question yesterday (update instead of delete) I'll point you to that [How can i update a field of my spinner with user input in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330096/how-can-i-update-a-field-of-my-spinner-with-user-input-in-edittext/46332833#46332833).

---

#### Specific Answers:

You can make the following change (as you extract the ID column into an array) :-

Change line

```
        dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                DbHelper.MEAL_ID + "=" + mealId.get(arg2), null);
```

to

```
        dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,DbHelper.MEAL_ID + "=" +
                    mealId.get(arg2),null);
```

So you are using position as the index to the mealId array, which then has the correct ID.

---

Note! Ideally `mealId` should be a `Long` not String and the above would then be:-

```
        dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,DbHelper.MEAL_ID + "=" +
                    Long.toString(mealId.get(arg2)),null);
```

Along with

```
        mealName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_NAME)));
```

being changed to

```
        mealName.add(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_NAME)));
```

---

#### Working Example comparing ArrayAdapter and CursorAdapter

Here's a close resemblance of your code using both an ArrayAdpater (DBHlper should close reflect yours (at least for the relavant/used columns))

*Note! uses ArrayAdapter not DisplayAdapter (which I guess is a Custom Adapter).*

:-

Class Variables :-

```
    DbHelper mHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    ArrayList<String> mealName = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> mealId = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    Cursor mCursor2;
```

Code in **Activity's `onCreate`** (or invoked by `onCreate`) :-

```
    mHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    userList2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);


    // Add some data (note will add rows each time this is run)
    mHelper.insertMeal("Fish");
    mHelper.insertMeal("Beef");
    mHelper.insertMeal("Lamb");
    mHelper.insertMeal("Rice");


    // Array method
    // Looks shorter but relies upon code if displayData
    userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,DbHelper.MEAL_ID + "=" +
                    Long.toString(mealId.get(i)),null);
            displayData();
        }
    });

    // Alternative using Cursor Adapter and thus long l (4th parameter) (the ID)
    // No Need for intermediate arrays, uses the cursor directly
    // (Only calls displayData to sync lists)
    userList2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            dataBase.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,DbHelper.MEAL_ID + "=" +
            Long.toString(l),null);
            mCursor2 = dataBase.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
            sca.swapCursor(mCursor2);
            // keep userList in sync with userList2
            displayData();
        }
    });

    //Initial setup of userList2
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mCursor2 = dataBase.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            mCursor2,
            new String[] {DbHelper.MEAL_NAME},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
            0
    );
    userList2.setAdapter(sca);

    //Initial setup of userList
    displayData();
}
```

The **displayData** method (*only really needed for ArrayAdpater other than it's called to sync both lists*):-

```
private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null);
    mealId.clear();
    mealName.clear();
    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
        mealId.add(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_ID)));
        mealName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.MEAL_NAME)));
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,
                mealName
        );
        userList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
    // keep userlist 2 in sync userList
    mCursor2 = mCursor; // cheat by using userList's cursor
    sca.swapCursor(mCursor2);
}
```

Example display:-

[image]

After clicking **Lamb** (1st item) in the **Left** List (ArrayAdapter) :-

[image]

After clicking **Beef** (now 3rd item) in the **Right** List (CursorAdapter) :-

[image]